# How to understand this code line in this MDN example: Rotating a shape around its center

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I came across a canvas example which explains [rotating a shape around its center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate#rotating_a_shape_around_its_center) and I found out a code line was hard to understand:

```js
// Matrix transformation
ctx.translate(150, 75);
ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
ctx.translate(-150, -75);
```

Why the values are these numbers? It's hard to understand as I can't see the matrix.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am not familiar with canvas. So I draw some sketches to help to understand.

Now I am more clear and familiar with the canvas stuff.

## Step1

[image]

## Step2

[image]

## Step3

[image]

## Step4

[image]